# Adding image resources to iOS app for tvOS

Tags: ios, xcode, tvos, apple-tv

I have an old iOS app and I am trying to add tvOS support to it.
I have some image resources that are named following Apple's standards for all scales:

```
image.png
image@2x.png
image@3x.png
```

I know that you can have different images for iPhone and iPad by adding the device to the name of the image like this([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html)):

```
image~iphone.png
image~ipad.png
```

So I was wondering if there is such a naming convention for the Apple TV, so it will take the appropriate image. I am thinking about something like `image~tvos.png` or something like that, but I couldn't find anything like that anywhere.

To give more context, with the way the UI is built, I would like to use the `image@2x.png` resources, but that won't work because the tvOS has a scale of 1([link](http://arctouch.com/2015/11/apple-tv-developers/)).

Does anyone know about this, or at least know it doesn't exist?